# do not know how to get the result of completion

Tags: swift, completion

I am having trouble to use the result of a completion handler.
I am getting this error "Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type"

```
struct SearchCollectionViewModel {
    let name: String
    let previewURL: String?
    var image:UIImage?
    let dataController = DataController()
}

extension SearchCollectionViewModel {
    init(with result: Result) {
        self.name = result.trackName
        self.previewURL = result.previewURL
        if let url = result.previewURL {
            let imgData = preview(with: url, completion: { data -> Data? in
                guard let data = data as? Data else { return nil }
                return data
            })
            self.image = UIImage(data: imgData)
        }
    }

    private func preview(with url: String, completion: @escaping (Data) -> Data?) {
        dataController.download(with: url) { data, error  in
            if error == nil {
                guard let imageData = data else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    _ = completion(imageData)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A completion handler cannot return a value. The whole idea makes no sense. To whom would it return anything?

Comment: Remove the return and move the line under, `self.image =...`, inside the completion handler instead

Comment: The whole idea that you are going to network asynchronously and return something during `init` is utterly misconceived.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of observations:

1. You cannot “return” a value that is retrieved asynchronously via escaping closure.
2. The closure definition `(Data) -> Data?` says that the closure not only will be passed the `Data` retrieved for the image, but that the closure will, itself, return something back to `preview`. But it’s obviously not doing that (hence the need for `_`, as in `_ = completion(...)`). I’d suggest you change that to `(Data?) -> Void` (or use the `Result<T, U>` pattern).
3. I’d suggest renaming your `Result` type as there’s a well-known generic called `Result<Success, Failure>` for returning `.success(Success)` or `.failure(Failure)`. This is a pattern that we’ve used for a while, but is formally introduced in Swift 5, too. See [SE-0235](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0235-add-result.md).

   Your codebase can have its own `Result` type, but it’s an invitation for confusion later down the road if and when you start adopting this `Result<T, U>` convention.
4. You really shouldn’t be initiating asynchronous process from `init`, but instead invoke a method to do that.
5. Personally, I’d move the conversion to `UIImage` into the `DataController`, e.g.

   ```
   extension DataController {
       func downloadImage(with url: URL, completion: @escaping (UIImage?, Error?) -> Void) {
           let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
               let image = data.flatMap { UIImage(data: $0) }
               completion(image, error)
           }
           task.resume()
       }
   }
   ```

---

So, I might suggest you end up with something like:

```
class SearchCollectionViewModel {
    let name: String
    let previewURL: String?
    let dataController = DataController()
    var image: UIImage?

    init(with result: Result) {
        self.name = result.trackName
        self.previewURL = result.previewURL
    }
}

extension SearchCollectionViewModel {
    func preview(with url: String, completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {
        guard let urlString = previewURL, let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }

        dataController.downloadImage(with: url) { [weak self] image, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.image = image
                completion(image)
            }
        }
    }
}
```